# How can I combine .toggleClass() with .appendTo()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I append a new class to a HTML container. How can I toggle this on/off by clicking on the menu button?
And is it even "best practice" to write more complex HTML code in JavaScript or would you prefer another method for this? Because I plan to do this for some more containers. Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $( "a.header-login" ).click(function() {
        $("<div class='sub-menu'>" +
        "<h2>Hi x!</h2>"+ 
        "<a class='item' href='#'>Logout</a>"+ 
        "</div>")
        .appendTo("header .header-r");
    })
});
```

Comment: Depending upon how strictly you adhear to the separation of concerns principle, you may want to put your html in a template and have the javascript grab it from there, rather than putting it directly in your javascript

Comment: Where are you adding this class you want to toggle, and to what element? All I can see in your code is you append a div with some content on click...?

Comment: You can just write the html as real html, then hide it with css and showing it with javascript

Comment: can i assume the html you have in the nested jquery selector is what you intend to append to the parent jquery object?

Comment: Thanks. So I actually just want to accomplish that another click on "a.header-login" deletes the container ".sub-menu".
Now, it is always generated when you click "a.header-login"

Comment: Sounds like an if conditional on the selection of the sub menu.  If it exists, delete it, if not, create it

Comment: @Taplar Yep, I also thought that but was looking for a probably better method.

Comment: "better" how?  You're asking how to solve a problem.  After you solve it, **then** you can start worrying about optimizing

Comment: Yes, I could "pre-generate" all code in HTML and set "display: none" to certain containers in the initial CSS load. But is that really best practice? I think it's a bit unclean. However, this project uses also PHP which leads to further issues when doing all of the additional containers in JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to accomplish that another click on "a.header-login" deletes the container ".sub-menu". Now, it is always generated when you click "a.header-login"

In this case you need to add a condition to check whether or not the element already exists. If it doesn't create it, if it does remove it.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  $('a.header-login').click(function() {
    var $target = $('header .header-r .sub-menu');
    if ($target.length === 0) {
      $('<div class="sub-menu"><h2>Hi x!</h2><a class="item" href="#">Logout</a></div>').appendTo('header .header-r');
    } else {
      $target.remove();
    }
  })
});
```

That being said, you can make this much simpler logic if you always include the `.sub-menu` in the HTML of your page but hide it with CSS by default. In that case your jQuery would become a simple call to `toggle()`:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  $('a.header-login').click(function() {
    $('header .header-r .sub-menu').toggle();
  })
});
```